# Java javax.mail, msal4j Oauth2 send email using Office 365

Tags: email, oauth-2.0, smtp, jakarta-mail, msal4j

I would like to send a e-mail. I use Java 1.8, com.microsoft.aad.msal4j und javax.mail.
However, I get the following error. No matter what I specify:

```
5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [........PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-10-07T15:04:28.150Z ....]
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [........PROD.OUTLOOK.COM 2023-10-07T15:04:28.150Z ...]

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
```

I have already tried that:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74899182/how-to-read-my-outlook-mail-using-java-and-oauth2-0-with-application-regsitratio?rq=3) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74056258/java-oauth2-send-email-using-office-365/77250353#77250353) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74056258/java-oauth2-send-email-using-office-365/77250353#77250353)

Unfortunately you can hardly find documentation and the test implementations here
[4](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/tree/dev/msal4j-sdk/src/test/java/com/microsoft/aad/msal4j) are not good either.

I use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

Works for me though only for .default or https://outlook.office365.com/.default as scope.

Here is my implementation (short version):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, MessagingException, MalformedURLException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
    props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth.xoauth2.disable", "false");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth.login.disable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth.plain.disable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

    IAuthenticationResult t = tokenFor("https://outlook.office365.com/.default").get();
    String token = t.accessToken();

    transport.connect("smtp.office365.com", 587, "user@foo.com", token);
    transport.send(new MimeMessage(session));
}

private static CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> tokenFor(String... scopes) throws MalformedURLException {

    String tenantId = "...";
    String clientId = "...";
    String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/v2.0/token";

    String authority = String.format(url, tenantId);

    String clientSecret = "...";

    IClientCredential secret = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret);

    ConfidentialClientApplication.Builder app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, secret)
            .authority(authority);

    ClientCredentialParameters.ClientCredentialParametersBuilder clientCredentialParam =
            ClientCredentialParameters.builder
                    (new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(scopes)));

    return app.build().acquireToken(clientCredentialParam.build());
}
```

Can someone try this ?